# Retrieve data over a many-to-many relationship in a Spring/Hibernate project

Tags: spring, hibernate, many-to-many, relationship

I am new to development using Spring framework and Hibernate. And I need to know what is the best practice to retrieve data from multiple tables. Here is a simple scenario:

Assuming a many-to-many relationship with these tables: Students(sid, name), Courses(cid, title), Students-Courses(sid,cid)

I don't have a Model/Entity class for Students-Courses. Here is how I handled the relationship in the "Student" Model/Entity class:

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
    name = "students-courses",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "sid", referencedColumnName = "sid")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "cid", referencedColumnName = "cid")})
```

So, this class creates both "Students" and "Students-Courses" tables in the database via Hibernate. I also have a separate Model/Entity class for Course.

How can I get the list of all the students including their courses (titles)? I mean multiple records for the students with more than one course

I can create an attribute in the "Student" class like this:

```
private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();
```

But it won't be returned back if I use a JpaRepository interface/class like

```
return studentRepository.findAll();
```

since it's not a @Column.

Should I write native-SQL code in my class?
Should I create an Immutable Entity class so Hibernate create sort of a database-view object in the data layer?
What is the best practice and how should I do that?

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a customized DTO class and a new list manually. But I am still interested in doing it via the relationship and Spring/Hibernate features. So please let me know if you have an answer. Thanks